# Laravel, response json data into controller and make json_decode into view

Tags: php, json, laravel, frameworks

I want to make this,
   1. Controller return json data to view

```
$data =  Response::json(array('status' => FALSE, 'code' => 205, 'message' => 'Deneme', 'data' => null), 200 );

    return View::make('site.index.index')->with('data', $data);
```

2. view will make decode this data and will use.

```
{{ $data2 = @json_decode($data)  }}

{{ var_dump($data2) }}
```

json data going into view but don't decoding on array.

How can decode this data?

Comment: `Response::json` is meant to be the actual response returned by the controller (see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses), instead you have passed that response through to the view as data. It might help to clarify why you are using the json encoding step, instead of `$data =  array('status' => FALSE, 'code' => 205, 'message' => 'Deneme', 'data' => null), 200 );` and then `{{ var_dump($data) }}`.

Comment: Why do you want to decode json in the view? When you add data to viewbag, it should be already decoded, prepared and ready to place in the template. Template is not a place for data logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_encode(array('status' => FALSE, 'code' => 205, 'message' => 'Deneme', 'data' => null));

return View::make('site.index.index')->with('data', $data);
```